# Limit of electronics items to carry from HK via flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel, hand-luggage, fines

What is the limit on electronics items (laptops and tablets) that I can carry on a flight from Hong Kong?

Can someone give me an approximate idea about the cost of excess luggage charge in HK?

Comment: Part of the answer resides in logistic issues (weight, size, ...) and is a concern to your carrier, and part of the answer resides in custom rules at your destination.

Comment: Can you clarify if those are your own used items, or if you mean brand new items you just bought? Also what is your destination? The issues involved are the maximum size and weight of your carry on, the maximum number of batteries you are allowed to carry, and customs at your destination.

Comment: Baggage rules vary a lot with airline, ticket type, fare class and type of "excess": Overweight, extra peace, how much. etc.

Comment: @jcaron There are some used items and new items. The destination location is India.

Answer (score 3):

There are typical no limits on the amount of any electronics.
However, there are often *size* and *weight* limits, which implicitly limits your electronics count; and there are potential customs issues in the arrival country (but that's not really a flight limitation, but an immigration limitation).

In other words, if you manage to pack 100 iPhones in your carry-on and it weights less than 8 kg or whatever the limit is on that flight, the *airline* doesn't care.

Cost for excess luggage is specific to the airline, your booking class, and your status; there is no general answer.

Comment: There’s actually a limit of 15 devices containing Lithium-ion batteries (provided the batteries have a capacity below 100 Wh).

Answer (score 1):

The limit is not so much a "from" issue, but a "to". Hong Kong Customs don't care what you take with you when you leave. The airline might object to batteries in the cargo hold, and to an amount of batteries in cabin luggage that exceeds a certain number of Amps. But that's about it.

Customs at your destination will probably have a duty-free allowance on products you bring in, based on monetary value. So if you have new products that exceed a certain amount of money they might tax them. But that has nothing to do with HK.

As for excess weight, each airline has its own fare schedule, and you should enquire with the airline you're flying with.